# How to query from from joined table in Node.js and Sequlieze?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have to main table Book (atrributes: name, author) and Collection(atrribute: collection_name)and a table that joins them with Book.BelongsToMany(Collection) and Collection.BelongsMany(Book) association

Now I want to find the books by searching for name, author or collection_name

here is my query

```
router.get("/search", (req, res) => {
  const { term } = req.query;
  console.log(term)
  Book.findAll({
    include: [
      {
        model: Collection,
       
      },
    ],
    where: { 
      [Op.or]:[
      {name: { [Op.like]: "%" + term + "%" }},
      {author: { [Op.like]: "%" + term + "%"}}
      ]
    }
  }).then((book) => {
      res.status(200).json(book);
    })
    .catch((err) => res.status(404).json({ error: err }));
});
```

This query shows me correct results when I searched for name or author . But how to search for collection_name in this query? Plaese help me out

Comment: What is `Type` here in `Type.BelongsMany(Book)`?

Comment: @msrumon Sorry , It is Collection.. edited!

Comment: Okay. So inside `include`, you should be able to define conditions for the related model: `include:[{model:Collection,where:{[Op.or:[collection_name:[Op.like]:'%'+term+'%']]}}]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an alias name for Collection while joining using include and then query on the collection_name column. The dollar symbol ($) is used as a placeholder to reference columns from associated models.
You can also directly use model name with $.

```
Book.findAll({
    include: [
      {
        model: Collection,
        as: 'collection'
      },
    ],
    where: { 
      [Op.or]:[
      {name: { [Op.like]: "%" + term + "%" }},
      {author: { [Op.like]: "%" + term + "%"}},
      {'$collection.collection_name$': { [Op.like]: "%" + term + "%"}}}
      ]
    }
)
```